# Firefox 42.0 won't start anymore in 14.04 LTS (firefox:2547): GLib-GObject-WARNING

Tags: firefox

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS - Firefox ver 42.0 doesn't start anymore via Unity bar shortcut, one day after I installed the system.
I can turn it on via terminal (**sudo firefox** ), but displays  the following warnings:

> ~$ sudo firefox
>
> (firefox:2879): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised
>
> (firefox:2879): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised
>
> (firefox:2879): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised
>
> (firefox:2879): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Ignore that warning.

Comment: How about if you just type `firefox` without sudo on the terminal? You don't need sudo to run Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall Firefox run this in terminal to remove the package.

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

and then install it again

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

for some reason removing Firefox also removes `xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts` install them again by runing this command.

```
sudo apt-get install xul-ext-unity xul-ext-webaccounts
```

also Firefox shortcut on the Unity bar will be gone so you would want to add it back.

To add Firefox back to the Unity bar.
click on the Unity launcher then type in Firefox then simply drag the Firefox launcher to the Unity bar.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions. I reinstalled the entire OS before I got your feedback because I was in a rush. FYI, besides Firefox, Thunderbird and Truecrypt were failing as well. I suspect that something went wrong 2 days ago while I was configuring Firefox Options --> Privacy settings